# Can someone help me install mysql server on a Fedora 18 box?

Tags: linux, mysql, fedora-18

I get this message after running the following command:

```
# yum -y install mysql mysql-sever

Install  2 Packages (+1 Dependent package)
Upgrade             ( 2 Dependent packages)

Total size: 9.5 M
Downloading Packages:
Running Transaction Check
ERROR with transaction check vs depsolve:
openssl >= 0.9.7f-4 is needed by dovecot-1:2.1.17-1.fc18.i686
Please report this error in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Fedora&version=rawhide&component=yum
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
 yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx.2019-01-22.12-31.pdbzwL.yumtx
```

Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: What does `openssl version` return?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP rebuilt the box so the problem is no longer reproducible (see self-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I ended up building a new box with Fedora 29. Many more resources for help with various needs

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  If you accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark, that will indicate that the problem was "solved".  However, it won't do much good to keep this thread since the problem is no longer reproducible and the thread can't help anyone else with a similar problem.  You might want to consider just deleting both posts.